# Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports

Tags: http, node.js, permission-denied

I'm testing out an app (hopefully to run on heroku, but am having issues locally as well).  It's giving me an EACCES error when it runs http.Server.listen() - but it only occurs on some ports.

So, locally I'm running:

```
joe@joebuntu:~$ node
> var h = require('http').createServer();
> h.listen(900);
Error: EACCES, Permission denied
    at Server._doListen (net.js:1062:5)
    at net.js:1033:14
    at Object.lookup (dns.js:132:45)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1027:20)
    at [object Context]:1:3
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:150:22)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:42:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:132:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:387:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:564:14)
```

I don't have anything running on port 900 (or any of the other 20 ports I've tried), so this should work.  The weird part is that it **does** work on some ports.  For instance, port 3000 works perfectly.

What would cause this?

### Update 1:

I figured out that on my local computer, the EACCES error is coming because I have to run node as root in order to bind to those certain ports.  I don't know why this happens, but using sudo fixes it.  However, this doesn't explain how I would fix it on Heroku.  There is no way to run as root on Heroku, so how can I listen on port 80?

Comment: Ports less 1024 traditionally require elevated permissions. On Heroku you dont listen to port 80, you listen to the port they tell you to via environment variables, and let their routing layer handle the port 80 binding on the edge.

Comment: Your update 1 helped me. 'sudo node myporgram.js' made it run.

Comment: In case this helps anyone: double and triple check you are listening on a port *number*. Due to a bug I was listening on `some string` and then you get the confusing `EACCES` errpr.

Comment: @Marc you're right. The port needs to be a number, especially when using https server. I've posted an answer for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70950946/10030693

Comment: not clear what OS is

Answer (score 409, accepted):

#### Running on your workstation

As a general rule, processes running without root privileges cannot bind to ports below 1024.

So try a higher port, or run with elevated privileges via `sudo`.  You can downgrade privileges after you have bound to the low port using [`process.setgid`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setgid_id) and [`process.setuid`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setuid_id).

#### Running on heroku

When running your apps on heroku you have to use the port as specified in the PORT environment variable.

See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js

```js
const server = require('http').createServer();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`));
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to use the port provided by Heroku, and then they will do some magic behind the scenes to transfer that to port 80?  What if I want to run something not on port 80?

Comment: Yes. You can only listen to the port we tell you on $PORT

We take care of routing 80 or 443 to your port. The actual port changes all of the time as we move your dyno around.

At this point in time we only support publicly routing from 80 and 443.

Comment: @Will, any chance of that restriction lifting?  Specifically, being able to listen on ports other than 80 or 443?  That's a pretty restrictive set, all things considered.

Comment: Why do you want your app running on a different port than http and https?

Comment: What's the env variable for the ssl port? process.env.SSL_PORT?

Comment: @Will I would like to host a simple game server on Heroku. Unity needs to transfer `crossdomain.xml` via 843 port.

Comment: I got the same error on windows 10 OS even for ports 3000, 3001 etc. After I restart the machine it will automatically fix. How can I solve this without restating windows each time I see this error.

Comment: Note that you can allow ports binding for anything below 1024 using `setcap`, as explained over on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44864082/740553

Answer (score 367):

**#Windows**

Another one reason - maybe your **port has been excluded** by some reasons.

So, try open CMD (command line) under **admin rights** and run :

1. `net stop winnat`
2. `net start winnat`

[image]

In my case it was enough.

Solution found here  : https://medium.com/@Bartleby/ports-are-not-available-listen-tcp-0-0-0-0-3000-165892441b9d

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. However, can anybody explain what has caused this problem suddenly?

Comment: Worked for me on windows 11, much appreciated!

Comment: This is a temporary fix. Mine was caused by Hyper-V. Luckily, there is a workaround.

Comment: Lifesaver!! Lost a few hours trying to grasp what's happening on my Win10 machine. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: solved the issue like a charm!!

Answer (score 212):

Non-privileged user (not root) can't open a listening socket on ports below 1024.

Comment: Upvoted - this is a good general rule, but there are exceptions to this, eg, 'capabilities' on Linux.

Comment: I dont like this though, i dont want to have to `sudo` when running an express server using node (gulp actually).   So doesnt make sense

Comment: @blamb Then use [MeetMehta's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23281417/1028230) ;^)

Comment: But I'm running my server at :5050 which is a lot higher than port 1024! Why isn't it working? I'm getting this: `Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:5050`

Comment: Never mind I solved this by changing my port from 5050 to port 5000. Just leaving my comment here for the sake of other developers facing the same problem as me that already has a port higher than 1024. (Just change it to other port--5000 recommended.)

Answer (score 135):

Check this [reference link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps#give-safe-user-permission-to-use-port-80):

> Give Safe User Permission To Use Port 80
>
> Remember, we do NOT want to run your applications as the root user,
>   but there is a hitch: your safe user does not have permission to use
>   the default HTTP port (80). You goal is to be able to publish a
>   website that visitors can use by navigating to an easy to use URL like
>   `http://ip:port/`
>
> Unfortunately, unless you sign on as root, you’ll normally have to use
>   a URL like `http://ip:port` - where port number > 1024.
>
> A lot of people get stuck here, but the solution is easy. There a few
>   options but this is the one I like. Type the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
> sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep `readlink -f \`which node\``
> ```
>
> Now, when you tell a Node application that you want it to run on port
>   80, it will not complain.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution.

Comment: @MarkLagendijk: Thanks Mark. I also asked the same question mistakenly and posted detailed answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281895/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-http-80-port-permission-denied. Feel free to edit it as well.

Comment: why isn't this the answer 

Comment: @KhaledMohamedP: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Who says this still not works with pm2 module. Kill your pm2 using `pm2 kill` and recreate it.

Comment: Thank you! This should be the answer, yes sudo will "fix" it too, but it's kind of a dirty trick

Answer (score 69):

On Windows System, search for **Services** then restart the "Host Network Service", it will resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: This needs more upvotes! Thank you - sometimes I ran into this problem and always had to restart the whole machine.

Comment: This solved the issue for me! Can anyone help me understand why and how?

Comment: finally an answer better than restarting!

Comment: it's solved my issue, it's still working until now.

Comment: solved mine too in a 14.x node app

Answer (score 57):

If you are using **Windows**. You should try restarting **Windows NAT Driver service**.

Open **Command Prompt** as **Administrator** and run

```
net stop winnat
```

then

```
net start winnat
```

That's it.

It's happening because I installed **Nord VPN** and it was auto staring with windows.

Comment: Much thanks this was my issue.

Answer (score 15):

Spoiler alert: This answer may seems little funny.

I have spent more than 10 minutes to find out the root cause for this error in my system. I used this : `PORT=2000;` in my .env file.

Hope you already find it out. I had used a semicolon after declaring PORT number :'( I removed the extra sign and it started working.

I know this may not be answer for this question but hope it helps others who have faced same problem.

Comment: Okay I did the same mistake and couldn't find the error and wasted a day . This answer helped me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, bro. I did the same mistake :-)

Comment: I found this answer after solving the same problem :)

Comment: @luffy .. you are the saviour.... I did the same .. added semicolon (PORT=3000;) after reading your suggestion I removed semicolon (PORT=3000) .. and lo behold. it worked .. I have already spent a day trying all the other solutions but nothing worked except your solution

Answer (score 10):

Another approach is to make port redirection:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 900 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

And run your server on >1024 port:

```
require('http').createServer().listen(3000);
```

ps the same could be done for https(443) port by the way.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! This saved me one hour of debugging for safe ports, another hour for SSL redirection, and also allowed me to restrict the visibility of a development server on AWS Lightstail (which does not allow fine-tuning of requests by IP address).

Answer (score 7):

OMG!! In my case I was doing `....listen(ip, port)` instead of `...listen(port, ip)` and that was throwing up the error msg: `Error: listen EACCES localhost`

I was using port numbers >= 3000 and even tried with admin access. Nothing worked out. Then with a closer relook, I noticed the issue. Changed it to `...listen(port, ip)` and everything started working fine!!

Just calling this out in case if its useful to someone else...

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem. I'm used to all other APIs using hostname, port.

Comment: I had this problem when I trying run Wekan docker image. I solved using this tip. Thank you.

Comment: @dilip-muthukurussimana Did you intend to have `....listen(ip, port)` in your answer (with four `.`)? It took me a minute to realize you were talking about the order of the arguments because of that.

Comment: Yes, I meant only the order of arguments. Pls don't put `....` (four dots) there, which I thought was obvious.

Comment: The reverse was the case for me. I am using Nodejs v14.17.5  I had been using  `....listen(port, IP)` and it was throwing errors `listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1`.  I saw your answer, which made me pay closer attention to the error, I changed it to  `....listen(ip, port)` and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem that it was denying to run on port 8080, but also *any* other.

Turns out, it was because the `env.local` file it read contained comments after the variable names like:

```
PORT=8080 # The port the server runs at
```

And it interpreted it like that, trying to use port "`8080 # The port the server runs at`", which is obviously an invalid port (-1). 
Removing the comments entirely solved it.

Using Windows 10 and Git Bash by the way.

---

I know it's not *exactly* the problem described here, but it might help someone out there. I landed on this question searching for the problem for my answer, so... maybe?

Comment: Yep, I've experienced this. Comments after values in .env files can cause this.

Answer (score 4):

It means node is not able to listen on defined port. Change it to something like 1234 or 2000 or 3000 and restart your server.

Answer (score 4):

restart was not enough! The only way to solve the problem is by the following:

You have to kill the service which run at that port.

at cmd, run as admin, then type :
`netstat -aon | find /i "listening"`

Then, you will get a list with the active service, search for the port that is running at 4200n and use the process id which is the last column to kill it by

: `taskkill /F /PID 2652`

Answer (score 4):

## 2023

### Linux (any distribution)

You can use `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` which is one of the [core Linux capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

> **CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE**
> Bind a socket to Internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).

You can give a permanent permission to any binary you wish to access < 1024 ports.

For Node.js for example, it would look like (you may need to use `sudo`):

```bash
setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip $(which node)
```

You can also remove this permission later on if you wish by running:

```bash
setcap -r $(which node)
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you are on windows OS.**

start terminal as an **Administrator**.

Then run

```
net start winnat
```

It will stop the windows NAT Driver service and then again run

```
net start winnat
```

It will start the windows NAT Driver service.

Then **go to your project folder** and start your script.
may be
`npm run start` or `npm run dev`

Answer (score 2):

I got this error on my mac because it ran the apache server by default using the same port as the one used by the node server which in my case was the port 80. All I had to do is stop it with `sudo apachectl stop`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Remember if you use sudo to bind to port 80 and are using the env variables PORT & NODE_ENV you must reexport those vars as you are now under root profile and not your user profile. So, to get this to work on my Mac i did the following:

```
sudo su
export NODE_ENV=production
export PORT=80
docpad run
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error on my mac too. I use `npm run dev` to run my Nodejs app in Windows and it works fine. But I got this error on my mac - `error given was: Error: bind EACCES null:80`.

One way to solve this is to run it with root access. You may use `sudo npm run dev` and will need you to put in your password.

It is generally preferable to serve your application on a non privileged port, such as 3000, which will work without root permissions.

reference: [Node.js EACCES error when listening on http 80 port (permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281895/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-http-80-port-permission-denied)

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is that,

**Solution 1:** I find that my `.env file` is incorrect. You should `not put ',' or ';'` separator between the variables.`

**Solution 2:** If it's a react app be sure you're in the client directory and that you're `not trying` to run your react app `in the server directory` (not give you an error but address the issue.)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was happening because the port used belong to reserved ports for Hyper-V.

This port range changes when I restart my computer, so sometimes I used to get the error and sometimes I don't.

It happened as I was building multiple Nextjs apps, and suddenly I'm unable to start one. I tried elevating the CMD to admin but access denied error, even tried finding the process associated with port but there was none.

I tried multiple ports like 3001, 3002, 3006, 3009 etc but nothing worked.

Here's the error: Error while starting Nextjs app, EACCES null:3001

[image: Error while starting Nextjs app, EACCES null:3001]

In order to check reserved ports by Windows you can use cmd/powershell with:

`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

[image: checking reserved ports in windows]

The issue is described in: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5514

**General workround** (in comment 554587817): https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171#issuecomment-554587817

**Fast workround:** choose a port that not belong to reserved ranges

`npm run dev -- -p 4000`

OR

Add the port specifier in the scripts section of package json file by editing dev, like this:

`"dev": "next dev -p 4000"`

and now it works:

[image: starting nextjs app with custom port]

This is also mentioned in the [post here](https://superuser.com/questions/1437780/how-to-fix-listen-eacces-permission-denied-on-any-port).

Answer (score 1):

this happens if the port you are trying to locally host on is portfowarded

Answer (score 1):

Try authbind:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html

After installing, you can add a file with the name of the port number you want to use in the following folder: /etc/authbind/byport/

Give it 500 permissions using chmod and change the ownership to the user you want to run the program under.

After that, do "authbind node ..." as that user in your project.

Answer (score 1):

My error is resolved using (On Windows)

```
app.set('PORT', 4000 || process.env.PORT);

app.listen(app.get('PORT'), <IP4 address> , () => {
    console.log("Server is running at " + app.get('PORT'));
});
```

Allow the NodeJS app to access the network in Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 1):

My error got resolved just by changing port number in server.js
Specially in this line

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8085;
```

I changed my port number to 8085 from 8080.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue affected all hosts and all ports on Windows in PowerShell.

**Disabling Network Interfaces fixed the issue.**

I had WiFi and an Ethernet connection and disabling the Ethernet Interface fixed this issue.

Open "Network Connections" to view your interfaces. Right-click and select "Disable".

Answer (score 1):

This means the port is used somewhere else. so, you need to try another one or stop using the old port.

Answer (score 1):

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 3000;
i add "PORT = 3000;" while "PORT = 3000" .
just semicolon";" give error
Before

```
PORT = 3000;
```

remove semicolon and project run successfully

After

```
PORT= 3000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I tried every answer given above, but nothing works out, then I figured out that I forget to add `const` before declaring the variable in the `.env` file.

Before:

```
PORT = 5000;
HOST = "127.0.0.1";
```

After:

```
const PORT = 5000;
const HOST = "127.0.0.1";
```

Answer (score 1):

So the possible reason for this would be related to typo in environment variables names or else not installed dotenv package .

So if there is any other error apart from typo and dotenv npm package ,then you must try these solutions which are given below:

**First solution**
for Windows only

Open cmd as run as administrator and then write two commands

1. `net stop winnat`
2. `net start winnat`

hope this may solve the problem ...

**Second solution**
for windows only

make sure to see that in your environment variable that there is no semicolon(;) at the end of the variable and there is no colon (:) after the variable name.

for example I was working on my project in which my env variables were not working so the structure for my .env file was like `PORT:5000; CONNECTION_URL:MongoDbString.<password>/<dbname>;` so it was giving me this error

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 5000;
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1313:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1476:5)
at Function.listen (E:\MERN REACT\mern_memories\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at file:///E:/MERN%20REACT/mern_memories/server/index.js:29:9
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '5000;',
port: -1
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

So i did some changes in my env file this time i removed the colon(:) and replaced it with equal(=) and removed semi colon at the end so my .env file was looking like this

```
PORT = 5000
CONNECTION_URL = MongoDbString.<password>/<dbname>
```

After changing these thing my server was running on the port 5000 without any warning and issues

Hope this may works...

#code #developers #mernstack #nodejs #react #windows #hostservicenetwork #http #permission-denied #EACCES:-4092

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different ways, re-installing IIS on my windows solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me.
You need to check out your *server.js* file where you are setting your listening port. Change port number wisely in all places, and it will solve your issue hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was just an error in the .env file. I deleted the comma at the end of each line and it was solved.

Before:

```
HOST=127.0.0.1,
```

After:

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that it was denying to run on port 5000,

Turns out, it was because the env.local file contained comma(';') after variable names like:

PORT= 5000;
And it interpreted it like that, trying to use port "5000;", which is obviously an invalid port (-1). Removing the ';' entirely solved it.

I know it's not exactly the problem described here, but it might help someone out there. I landed on this question searching for the problem for my answer, so... maybe?

Comment: Please target the answer to the question here. Look for the relevant parts. Answering a different question, even if similar, is not appropriate.

Comment: On the other hand, if this does answer the question, but only with info which is already in other answers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71235768/7733418 ) this answer is not needed at all either.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly fine for me, set your port at the bottom of the page with this code instead

```
     let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
    port = 3000;
}

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('app started successfully')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is because of bad configuration the dot.env like: require("dotenv").config without ()  in your app middle ware or may be you write your port number with wrong syntax like instead of = you write : or add some other symbols in port number.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the issue was in the `.env` file when defining the `PORT` number shouldn't have a `;` at the end rather should be like `PORT=3000` and make sure to add `require('dotenv').config()` before using the port number in the enviroment variable.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the issue was exiting my node application before without closing the express running server.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use this code  in main file**
const PORT = process.env.PORT || APP_PORT;

Answer (score -1):

if anyone is still facing this issue then follow  the below step.
open command line as Administrator and enter

> **net stop http**
> command,
> It will stop all service, which you are using port 80.

Now run your project, it will work for windows OS..