# socket.io binding to a specific ip address

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a windows server running IIS and node.js with socket.io for an interactive whiteboard application I am developing.  I want both the IIS website and node.js server to listen on port 80, but be bound to different IP addresses.

From what I can find, socket.io doesn't have the ability to specify ip address.  This limitation can supposedly be overcome by creating an http server instance.  I'm new to socket.io and node.js and am a little lost trying to do this.  I'll include the original server code (that listens on a specific port) and my attempt to instantiate a server on a specific IP address.

Original

```
(function() {
  var io;
  io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('drawClick', function(data) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('draw', {
        x: data.x,
        y: data.y,
        type: data.type
      });
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

Modified

```
(function() {
    var host = "10.70.254.76";
var port = 80;

var http = require("http").createServer();
var io = require("socket.io").listen(http);

http.listen(port, host);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('drawClick', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('draw', {
            x: data.x,
            y: data.y,
            type: data.type
        });
    });
});
}).call(this);
```

I get Error: listen EACCES when starting the modified code

Comment: Ok, My modified code works if I set the port to 8080.  I get the EACCES error when I try to use 80

Comment: port 80 is prohibited as it belongs to sudoers (root users), you can force it using "sudo node app.js" but is not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

The problem actually lies with IIS and it's socket pooling behavior.  IIS automatically reserves port 80 for all IP addresses (even if they are not currently bound to a site).
What I had to do was use the netsh command to override the default bindings and bind ip addresses via the netsh command.

Here's what I did.  This solution works for IIS 7 in Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress x.x.x.x
net stop http
net start http
net start w3svc
```

In my case I only have one active website being served by IIS and only had one IP bound to it.  This freed up my secondary IP address for node to listen on it and port 80.

Answer (score 10):

i see nobody answered, so i'll post this, not sure if it'll help you:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(8080, 'localhost');
var socket = io.listen(server);
```

basically just switch the calls to listen.

Comment: That's a permission error, right? Does it work, if you run it as sudo? Not that that's the recommended solution.

Comment: here is a link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports

Comment: Well, I get EACCES when I use port 80 with the modified method, but I don't get any error when using port 80 with the first method( the one that doesn't bind to a specific IP).  It's a windows box, and the command is being run as administrator.

Comment: Never mind, I found out it was actually an issue with how IIS behaves.  I added my solution above.

Comment: @ämbi:  can we add more then one IP address.. I need to create a webservice accesible from one IP address only... I believe can use this as a nice solution?