# Node.js EACCES error when listening on http 80 port (permission denied)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, permission-denied

Node.js throws following error while running on http port 80 (default port):-

```
Error: EACCES, Permission denied
    at Server._doListen (net.js:1062:5)
    at net.js:1033:14
    at Object.lookup (dns.js:132:45)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1027:20)
    at [object Context]:1:3
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:150:22)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:42:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:132:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:387:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:564:14)
```

I figured out that node needs to have root access.

Conventionally we avoid giving root access in normal situation. What's the best practices for using it on port 80 (or port<1024).

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode) has the same question but it has only one answer i.e. PREROUTING. While my solution provides other ways as well.

I am writing this to have all answers at one location, as I have to go thorough other resources than PREROUTING. Why not all answers at one location for sharing the knowledge

Comment: @bryanph: I provided reference link in answers. Pls check. Also, I provided with more solutions :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

FYI: You cannot run socket on ports < 1024 with normal user permission. You need to have root access for it.

### There are total 3 ways to solve the error:-

---

### 1. Give root access and run it (which is usual one)

### 2. Redirect to other port

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Then launch my Node.js on port 3000. Requests to port 80 will get mapped to port 3000.

You should also edit your /etc/rc.local file and add that line minus the sudo. That will add the redirect when the machine boots up. You don't need sudo in /etc/rc.local because the commands there are run as root when the system boots.

Reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode/23281401#23281401)

### 3. Give Normal user capability of using sockets as root

Objective:- We are not providing full root access and only giving socket_root permission to access it by normal user to run your server on any port.

we do NOT want to run your applications as the root user, but there is a hitch: your safe user does not have permission to use the default HTTP port (80). You goal is to be able to publish a website that visitors can use by navigating to an easy to use URL like `http://localhost`.

Unfortunately, unless you sign on as root, you’ll normally have to use a URL like `http://localhost:3000` - notice the port number.

A lot of people get stuck here, but the solution is easy. There a few options but this is the one I like. Type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep `readlink -f \`which node\``
```

Now, when you tell a Node application that you want it to run on port 80, it will not complain.

Reference [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps#give-safe-user-permission-to-use-port-80)

General Info Reference [link](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NonRootPortBinding) from apache

Comment: It should be noted that you generally should not run a server as root without dropping privileges afterward.

Comment: @mscdex: yes. You are absolutely right. But with #3 solution you are only providing socket access capabilities instead of all (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

Comment: answer came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode

Comment: My comment was about solution #1. Solution #3 is an alright solution, provided that you trust _any/all_ scripts executed with node. Dropping privileges after starting with root allows you to do this on a per-script basis.

Comment: @bryanph: Pls check my answer properly. I already provided reference links. Its better for you to go through my answer first before commenting

Comment: @mscdex: ya got that point. can you pls elaborate per-script basis! I think I got that but still its for clarification

Comment: The `setcap` method applies to the binary itself not a particular script. So any time you use the node binary (even the REPL), it will be able to listen on any port. However that may not be desirable (for security or other reasons).

Comment: @mscdex: I got that part. But by setting only socket_listen capability, imo its somewhat more secure than giving root permissions and then running node. What's your suggestion to use :80 by nodejs (imo - #3 is good)

Comment: sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep `readlink -f \`which node\`` worked for me. Thanks