# Start a https without port number using npm http-server on Mac

Tags: macos, ssl, npm, https, httpserver

I am using npm http-server to start a https server with:

```
http-server --ssl --cert ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.crt --key ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.key
```

It defaults to 8080 port. So I can use `https://192.168.22.123:8080` to access.  But I wanted to not have to specify 8080 at all, for ex: `https://192.168.22.123`.  Can it be done?

According to [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) there is a `-p` or `--port` option. But not sure if or how to do it?

Edited: It seemed like I can redirect to any ports other than well known ports.  For example, I have no problem with 8081 or 4000.  But if I specified 80, it gave me an error:  events.js with Unhandled 'error' and Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:80.  I did see other posts that people were using 80.

Any suggestions why mine is not working?

Comment: On Unix for a (server) program to use a port number below 1024 either you must be running as `root` or on some variants, I don't know for MacOS, the process must have `CAP_NET_BIND'. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281895/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/ https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579028/ Note using the default port is different from having no port at all, and the default for _HTTP_ is 80 but for HTTPS it's 443.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: That was it.  I was able to just use https without port (defaults to 443) using sudo.  Thanks.  If you would put this in the answer then I will make this as an accepted answer.