# Why does ec2 instance not display my website? Using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, centos, yeoman, mean-stack

I am running a m1.microinstance of aws, using CentOS. I downloaded Yeoman, git, npm and all of the dependencies are present. I am trying to run a MEAN stack on this server, so, mongo, express, angular and node. However, when I visit my public DNS, my site gives me this error: "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ec2-54-191-0-63.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com". On my admin control panel, I see my instance status, and it says it is running. I understand that if I had used apache, the page that displays is in the /var/www/html directory.. So, how do I get a directory similar to apaches, to display my html files, or whatever I would like the public to see? I have my security groups configured, for inbound, to listen to SSH port 22, for everyone, as well as HTTP port 80, for everyone.

Yeoman set up a nice app folder for me, but for some reason it does not display. I thought maybe I was missing a server.js, but that does not seem to have fixed anything when I added it. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your node instance is running and listening on port 80? Often it'll start on a higher port. The Express how-to starts listening on port 3000 `var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});` -

Comment: @pherris So, at first it was 8080, so now I changed it, and now I am getting a different error: listen EACCES errnoException(net.js:904:11)

Comment: Okay, I found the answer here: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/ … Basically, I just needed to run the command as sudo.

Comment: Cool, added an official answer so folks know what the solution was (and you can mark accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are matching the port all the way through - your browsers URL:PORT, the EC2 routing rules and your NodeJS settings. It looks like you might be listening to a port higher than 80 on the server.

As you mentioned in your comment, if you want to listen on a port below 1024 you will need to run the command as a privileged user.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't run node as root on my AWS server, so it was not setting up my nicely built app that Yeoman made for me.

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915 was where I realized my mistake. I am new to linux OS soo, I am learning. :)

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer - this is the answer to a subsequent problem you had which can only be found by reading the comments of your question. In the future, StackOverflow etiquette is to accept the answer that addresses the question that was asked (and posted by the folks here who are helping you). Feel free to use comments to add extra information e.g. the sudo requirement to listen on port 80.