# New to using NodeJS Express Server

Tags: node.js

I trying to view a static html page at localhost, but get the following error message:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at Function.app.listen (/home/phil/xProgramming/AngJS/Project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:536:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/phil/xProgramming/AngJS/Project/server.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I've tried killall, but I still get the same error message.

I new to Linux and am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports

Answer (score 1):

The EACCES error normally means that you are trying to bind to a port and failing. This is probably because you are trying to bind to port 80 without root permissions. Try running node with root permissions and it should work.

```
sudo node server.js
```

or

```
sudo nodejs server.js
```

Depending on how you have Ubuntu setup.

If this is a development environment instead of running as root you should use a port greater than 1024. Typically you will find people using port 3000 for node though 8000 and 8080 are also used. Here is how I normally do this when using Express.

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```