# deploying node add on server without using localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node app that I am trying to deploy on my server. I have an `index.html` file in a public folder and an `app.js` file. If I navigate to the project in the command line and run `node app.js` it runs the app on `localhost:8888` and shows the `index.html` file.

Now that I have uploaded this to my server I am wondering what I need to do, and change (if anything) in my `app.js` file so that i can visit the site without visiting `localhost:8888`, but instead the actual url.

I have tried `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/folderName/app/public:8888`, but this doesn't work.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(8888, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8888!')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Server" is a word with two primary meanings in software development.

It can mean either "A piece of software that listens on a network" or "A computer running that kind of software".

So having uploaded the JavaScript program to the remote computer that is your server you need to do exactly the same as you did on your own computer.

i.e. you need to get a terminal on the server and run `node app.js`

It will then be available at `http://your.example.com:8888/`

(More advanced uses would involve using software like forever or system.d to run it automatically as a background process).

---

If you were using the term server with the other meaning (i.e. you mean "Apache HTTP" or "IIS" or similar), then you are out of luck.

Using Node for server side code means running a server written in JavaScript.

To use this in combination with something like Apache, you would either:

1. Run the Node server instead of Apache
2. Run the Node server on a different port and point some services at that port explicitly
3. Run the Node server on a different port and use something like ProxyPass to have Apache relay requests to it

Comment: thanks @quentin - I have run `node app.js` in the terminal of the server and when i visit `localhost:8888` in the browser on the server it works. However, when I change the port to 80 as advised below i get the following error message `error: listen EACCES: 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: @phantom — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports

Comment: thanks @quentin. I changed it back to `8888` and it runs the file, but when i visit `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx/folderName/app/public:8888` it doesn't work. I guess the path is incorrect

Comment: Port numbers go after the hostname, not after the path.

Comment: You probably do not need `/folderName/app/public/` -- node takes care of that part. So `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx:8888` is probably all you need

Comment: @RobynOverstreet you're correct. It works with `http://162.xx.xxx.xxx:8888`. Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number from 8888 to 80 and then use the address of your server in the browser. For example, "mysite.com" for a domain name or "123.45.678" for an IP address.

If there are other sites on that server, you can't run it on port 80. (Port 80 is the default port websites use.) You'd need to use a different port. So, say you kept `8888` -- the address would be `yoursite.com:8888`

Comment: Yes, eventually you'd need forever or a similar app to keep it running, but you can test it out without using forever at first.

Comment: it won't run on port 80 - its saying `error: listen EACCES: 0.0.0.0:80` as there are other sites on that server also. there are different folders. make sense?

Comment: If there are other sites on that server, you can't run it on port 80. (Port 80 is the default port websites use.) You'd need to use a different port. So, say you kept 8888 -- the address would be yoursite.com:8888