# Google Compute Supervisord nodejs https

Tags: node.js, express, google-compute-engine, supervisord

I am trying to deploy a node.js app to Google Compute and have supervisord run it.

I have it working just fine when I try to have the app listen on port 3000.

When I try to move it to 443 so that I can use https so access the server it gives me errors when starting the app:

[image]

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('API online');
});

app.listen(443, function () {
  console.log(`API online`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably already a process which is attached to port 443. Maybe Apache or Nginx?
You can check with: sudo netstat -nlp|grep 443

Comment: Nothing running there apparently.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports  Ports bellow 1024 need elevated access to use. Try to start your node application as root.