# Running sockets.io in node without sudo access

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket.io node file that starts like this...

```
//sockets/server
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');
app.listen(80); //the 5th line that the error refers to
```

When I run from the console with "node myFile.js" I get the following error...

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1112:19)
    at listen (net.js:1155:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1240:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myUser/node/myFile.js:5:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

I can easily get around the error on my local machine (MAMP) by adding 'sudo' to the start of the command, but my hosting provider won't let me do that on the production environment.

Does anyone have any idea of a way to fix the error (or even know what it means) as opposed to sudoing it out of the way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)

Comment: Thanks Ben - you're right - don't know how I didn't find that post but it does describe the correct approach which just worked perfectly for me (as does the answer posted below by Tatsuyuki which I'll accept shortly).

Comment: You can also run your server on a higher number port that does not require those higher privileges (which keeps you from having to give your server root privileges) and then use iptable configuration to redirect port 80 to your higher port number.  I do this on my Raspberry Pi to keep from having to give my server process higher privileges, but it does successfully serve port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 80 is a privileged port, and you need `root` or `CAP_NET_ADMIN` to bind to it.

The solutions are:

1. Do not bind to port 80 for development.
2. Configure your system to allow the port to be used as a normal user. See: https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443

Comment: Yeah, well you got my upvote anyway - thanks for the answer - I chose 8080 and it works perfectly - will accept answer shortly...