# Why there is error " listen EACCESS localhost " in Given Code, What exactly it mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var express=require('express'),
    morgan=require('morgan');

var host='localhost';
var port=3000;


var app=express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){ 
    res.send('index.html');

})

app.listen(host,port,function(){

    console.log("The server is listning on port : "+port+"   Host :   "+host);
});
```

Comment: Something similar ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a fault in your code where you are trying to make app listen.

The syntax should be:

```
app.listen(PORT,HOST,callbackFunction);
```

but you are using:

```
app.listen(HOST,PORT,callbackFunction);
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen