# Meteor/Apollo: SSL Access for HTTPS and WS?

Tags: ssl, meteor, graph, websocket, apollo

I’m trying to get SSL working in Meteor for https and websockets. I’m getting this error:

```
(STDERR) Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443
```

Here's my setup.

For SSL access I have installed nourharidy/meteor-ssl. I can use any comparable package or approach that people have found useful!

As required by nourharidy/meteor-ssl, in `server/main.js` I have:

```
SSL('/path/to/private/server.key','/path/to/private/server.crt', 443);
```

Here's the rest of my setup:

My ROOT_URL environment variable is:

```
https://10.0.1.10:443 //I’m using my Mac’s ip address so that another Mac can access it
```

In `imports/startup/server/index.js` I have:

```
//SET UP APOLLO QUERY / MUTATIONS / PUBSUB
const USING_HTTPS = true;
const httpProtocol =  USING_HTTPS ? "https" : "http"; 
const localHostString = '10.0.1.10' //I’m using my Mac’s ip address so that another Mac can access it

const METEOR_PORT = 443;
const GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT = 4000;
const subscriptionsEndpoint = `wss://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT}/subscriptions`;

const server = express();
server.use('*', cors({ origin: `${httpProtocol}://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT}` }));
server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    schema
}));
server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql',
    subscriptionsEndpoint: subscriptionsEndpoint
}));
// We wrap the express server so that we can attach the WebSocket for subscriptions
const ws = createServer(server);
ws.listen(GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on ${httpProtocol}://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT}`);

    // Set up the WebSocket for handling GraphQL subscriptions
    new SubscriptionServer({
        execute,
        subscribe,
        schema
    }, {
        server: ws,
        path: '/subscriptions',
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info!

Comment: What have you tried to diagnose this problem? have you used Postman or curl to see what happens there? SImply dumping a bunch of code and an error message doesn't make it easy for us to help  you

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  I am not familiar with using postman or curl to debug this kind of situation.  What would be a good Google search to bring up more information on how to do this?

Comment: Seriously ? You need help to use Google? Really? You can go straight to Postman and read what it does  www.getpostman.com

Comment: I've heard of using Postman to debug REST calls, but never for this. I don't even know the name of whatever this is that we'd be using postman on. Would I google "postman for debugging websockets", for example?  Don't bother replying if you can't put in the effort to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! It turns out my server setup was fine.

Server-side I was building the WSS url like so:

```
var websocketUri = Meteor.absoluteUrl('subscriptions').replace(/http/, 'ws').replace('3100', '3200');
```

The Meteor docs for [absoluteUrl](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl) say:

> The server reads from the ROOT_URL environment variable to determine where it is running.

In Webstorm I have ROOT_URL set to `https://10.0.nn.nn:3100`. But for some reason absoluteUrl was returning `http://10.0.nn.nn:3000`.  I.e. it had the wrong port.

After correcting the port-- it’s working!

**UPDATE:** I thought I had it solved when I posted a few days ago, but I was still missing something.

I'm now using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to provide SSL to my dev system for use with HTTPS and WSS.

Here are a few details.

- I run Meteor on localhost:3000.
- I assign the value of "http://localhost:3000" to the ROOT_URL environment variable.
- I run two simultaneous ngrok connections, one for HTTPS and one for WSS:

`./ngrok http 3000 
./ngrok http 3200`

- This gives me two ngrok urls, for example:

> Forwarding  https://9b785bd3.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
>   Forwarding  https://ec3d8027.ngrok.io -> localhost:3200

I access my app via the ngrok url, for example:

> https://9b785bd3.ngrok.io

I build my HTTPS links and WSS links based on the ngrok addresses. For example:

`const wssEndpoint = 'wss://ec3d8027.ngrok.io/subscriptions';`

I hope this is helpful to others looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

The way Stack Overflow works is that you put some effort in, and get close to the problem, and we'll help you get through that last bit. Asking for help on how to use Google is what we call off-topic.

If you have done a Google search for `Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443` would have yielded a bunch of results, the first of which is this:

[Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)

So I am willing to be helpful, but you need to help yourself too

Comment: Thanks for this info. After hearing that it is okay to run HTTPS and WSS on the same port, I have set both `METEOR_PORT` and `GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT` to 3100. Both ports are now higher than port 1024 per the link provided. However, I am still getting the error  `listen EADDRINUSE :::3100`.  What is the correct way to fix this? Please let me know if I can provide additional relevant info.

Comment: I just set `METEOR_PORT` to 3100 and `GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT` to 3200 -- that has gotten rid of this particular error. However, there's another error now --- probably a topic for different thread. Thanks for your input.