# Node.js website with SSL, getting "Refused to connect" error

Tags: node.js, ssl

I've successfully created the SSL certificate and the key for my website via OpenSSL. I uploaded them in a folder on the server. I get no errors when I start the server.

But when I try to load the website in the browser using https://, I get the "refused to connect" error.

Here is the code I am using to create the https server:

```
var app = require('../app');
    var debug = require('debug')('gameserver:server');
    const https = require('https');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const options = {
        port: normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '80'),
        key: fs.readFileSync('../keys/key.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../keys/cert.crt')
    };

    var server = https.createServer(options);
    require('../config/socket')(server);

    server.listen(port);
    server.on('error', onError);
    server.on('listening', onListening);

    function normalizePort(val) {
        var port = parseInt(val, 10);

        if (isNaN(port)) {
            return val;
        }

        if (port >= 0) {
            return port;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function onError(error) {
        if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
            throw error;
        }

        var bind = typeof port === 'string'
            ? 'Pipe ' + port
            : 'Port ' + port;

        switch (error.code) {
            case 'EACCES':
                console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
                process.exit(1);
                break;
            case 'EADDRINUSE':
                console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
                process.exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                throw error;
        }
    }

    function onListening() {
        var addr = server.address();
        var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
            ? 'pipe ' + addr
            : 'port ' + addr.port;
        debug('Listening on ' + bind);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you try running in port 443? and proceed on browser using insecure certificate?

Comment: Already tried it, same result

Answer (score 0):

Your keys/cert are valid ?

The following command should display the same results:

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in mykey.key | openssl md5 ; openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in mykey.crt | openssl md5 ;
```

Or maybe node manage only .pem key file, simply concat the .key and the .crt in the .pem then use the .pem instead of the .key:

```
cat server.crt server.key > server.pem
```

Then verify the pem :

```
openssl verify -CAfile server.pem server.crt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. Indeed, it needed to be port 443. Also, in the createServer function I forgot to pass app as a parameter. Here is a working example:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('gameserver:server');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    port: normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '80'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('../keys/key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../keys/cert.crt')
};

    var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(443, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port 443");
});
require('../config/socket')(server);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
        ? 'Pipe ' + port
        : 'Port ' + port;

    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: Also, non-privileged user (not root) can't open a listening socket on ports below 1024.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports

Comment: and maybe you can also upvote the comment for at least suggesting port 443?