# node.js FS cannot read certificate from letsencrpyt

Tags: node.js, https, lets-encrypt

```
const httpsOptions = {
    key: FS.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/site/privkey.pem"),
    cert: FS.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/site/fullchain.pem")
};

EACCES: permission denied
```

Trying to set up a HTTPS server with options. While setting up the optiosn to pass to the `HttpS.createServer(httpsOptions,App);`. I got the cert from letsencrypt however trying to run the server results in permission denied errors. What is the correct way to load the cert and key file for the HTTPS server?

Comment: `EACCES` usually means you are trying to do something that only a user with additional privileges can do.  What user are you trying to run your server as?  What user owns those cert files?  What port are you trying to run your server on?  Is this question applicable? [Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9164915/691711).

Comment: @zero298 port 3200, the problem is that node will not read my certificate files, as I am trying to run it as a HTTPS server and not a plain HTTP server

Comment: @zero298 Just tried to run the serer like usual with, `nodemon server.js`. This works for HTTP but once I try to run the httpsOptions command, then I get the error. Is there another file location that I need access the certs from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificates doesn't have right permissions.

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/letsencrypt/live/
```

Try this. Hope it works

Comment: think this might have done the trick, not 100% sure as I had done some other configuration changes but this might have helped.

Comment: In my case, the certificates inside the directory need to have 644 permissions (read permission to other user). Because my nodejs server is run under a regular user.

Answer (score 19):

@Wesgur answer did not help in my case, what did help was:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /etc/letsencrypt/live/ -R
sudo chown $(whoami) /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ -R
```

Probably related to the fact that the **live** directory .pem files are symbolic links to the actual certificate and private key files in the **archive** directory...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer what does $(whoami) and -R do?

Comment: $(whoami) is a place holder and replace $(whoami) with the current SSH user name. Also -R is used to recursively change the owner.

Answer (score -1):

For those with this problem with let's encrypt:

- While in testing, simply start the server with sudo...e.g. `sudo node index.js`
- For production, make it run as a daemon started by a user with sudo privileges

This way you don't have to mess with file permissions or ownership

Comment: While this works, if an attacker gains control of the script by ACE, then they will also have access to the entire filesystem with all privileges. Code should only run with select privileges it requires, so **this answer is insecure.**

Comment: Which is why i didn't go this route.