# Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80 Error On Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi I'm trying to deploy our node.js app on Azure (Web/Mobile App). But it is giving that error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
```

My port listen code is:

```
httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

It was working on Google Cloud platform without any problem.

Comment: Are you trying to manually boot up that app? That would explain the binding error as `process.env.PORT` does not exist in Kudu but it does exist in the app namespace (IIS app pool). It's also not a TCP port number but a named pipe. What happens when you access the app on its public URL?

Comment: One more thing, if you didn't deploy with git you are probably missing the auto generated web.config. You can copy it from here -https://gist.github.com/davidebbo/8ad0d30ac1b1aa3d0334, just amend your startup file name.

Comment: @evilSnobu I deployed from local git, web.config generated succesfully, I think it is about deploying git and trying to start app from manually at the same time. I'm a noob on azure and try to understand processes.

Comment: Well, don't start your app manually. Just add the git remote as `https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net` and git push to it. Also, make sure you don't have a stray "PORT" App Setting in the portal for that Web App.

Answer (score -1):

If you're running your application without root privileges you will not be allowed to use ports lower than 1024, how about you try a port higher than that or run application as a root user.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, you're not allowed to run on ports lower than 1024. So, you can't just specify port 80.
For more details, refer [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports) which addressing your issue.