# Docker: Empty response from server

Tags: node.js, docker

I am having trouble to connect docker container, server returns empty response however the configuration seems to be correct.

When i use docker-compose up command everything seems fine and working however i am getting empty response from server.

I double checked the port mappings however i couldnt notice anything.

Here is the compose file

```
    version: '3'

    services: 
      authapi:
        build:
          dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.dev
          context: .
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - .:/usr/src/auth
          - /usr/src/auth/node_modules
        environment: 
          FBAPPID: ${FBAPPID}
          FBAPPSECRET: ${FBAPPSECRET}
          GOOGLEAPPID: ${GOOGLEAPPID}
          GOOGLEAPPSECRET: ${GOOGLEAPPSECRET}
          GITHUBAPPID: ${GITHUBAPPID}
          GITHUBAPPSECRET: ${GITHUBAPPSECRET}
        ports:
          - ${PORT}:${PORT}
        command: 
          - sh
          - -c
          - sleep 20 && npm run start:dev
        depends_on: 
          - psql
      psql:
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        environment: 
          POSTGRES_USER: ${PG_USER}
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PG_PASSWORD}
          POSTGRES_DB: ${PG_DB}
        volumes:
          - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM node:10-alpine

    WORKDIR /usr/src/auth

    COPY ./package.json .

    RUN npm install

    COPY . . 

    EXPOSE 9091

    CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

docker port response

```
9091/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9091
```

docker ps response

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
cecbf815523e        authservice_authapi   "sh -c 'sleep 20 && …"   15 
minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:9091->9091/tcp   
authservice_authapi_1
4e5c5f312703        postgres:10-alpine    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 
minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   
authservice_psql_1
```

here is docker network

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                  DRIVER              SCOPE
3bb18805e2b1        authservice_default   bridge              local
f7fb02e95fc3        bridge                bridge              local
815dccd6c8b8        host                  host                local
12ca56c3c08d        none                  null                local
```

authservice_default inspect response

```
        [
      {
          "Name": "authservice_default",
          "Id": "3bb18805e2b129342ce255017c88b8d72717f050419503d81042f5319b5f5009",
          "Created": "2018-09-26T18:24:01.3773204Z",
          "Scope": "local",
          "Driver": "bridge",
          "EnableIPv6": false,
          "IPAM": {
              "Driver": "default",
              "Options": null,
              "Config": [
                  {
                      "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                      "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Internal": false,
          "Attachable": true,
          "Ingress": false,
          "ConfigFrom": {
              "Network": ""
          },
          "ConfigOnly": false,
          "Containers": {
              "4e5c5f3127036fe300ec2917fd6023d00ca8d3c4e28b583107c2deabc6fd2dda": {
                  "Name": "authservice_psql_1",
                  "EndpointID": "461b8164f174d436a4a039ff9ff494cac3bc5f6f96c1b8d0619928c8dafb6652",
                  "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                  "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                  "IPv6Address": ""
              },
              "cecbf815523e4028c2b9cb1d74104ef61cc8fb8947624c9df8f035193842a9b0": {
                  "Name": "authservice_authapi_1",
                  "EndpointID": "af30a79b70d675002f12bd61ca8aed2d8d5f036bd99c10fa7a205cf3e21ae19b",
                  "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                  "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                  "IPv6Address": ""
              }
          },
          "Options": {},
          "Labels": {
              "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
              "com.docker.compose.project": "authservice",
              "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
          }
      }
    ]
```

logs of containers

```
    [nodemon] starting `node ./src/babel.start.js`
    {"level":30,"time":1537987440400,"msg":"Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:9091","pid":63,"hostname":"cecbf815523e","v":1}
    |-----------------------------Start-----------------------------|
    |                                                               |
    |              Server started on http://127.0.0.1:9091
    |                                                               |
    |---------------------------------------------------------------|
    |-----------------------------CPU INFO--------------------------|
    |                                                               |
    |  Cpu 0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz => speed 2697
    |  Cpu 1: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz => speed 2697
    |                                                               |
    |----------------------TOTAL MEMORY ----------------------------|
    |                                                               |
    |========================> 2 GB
    |                                                               |
    |-----------------------FREE MEMORY-----------------------------|
    |                                                               |
    |========================> 155.5 MB
    |                                                               |
    |------------------------PLATFORM-------------------------------|
    |                                                               |
    |========================> linux v4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs x64
    |                                                               |
    |---------------------------------------------------------------|
    |------------------------IFACE IP-------------------------------|
    |                                                               |
    |========================> 172.18.0.3
    |                                                               |
    |---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

i dont add here postgress one because application has nothing to do with postgress now.

Everything seems fine from my perspective, am i missing something ? Huge thanks already now for those who tries to help :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I have solved the problem by binding the application to 0.0.0.0 and everything started to work.

I hope it would be useful anybody who are looking for solution for this kind of issue.

Comment: How did you bind it to 0.0.0.0 exactly?

Comment: I was using Nodejs and express so i have bind the express application to 0.0.0.0

Comment: How you bind to `0.0.0.0` will depend on what type of application server you're running. For me, I was runnning python's `gunicorn` which [defaults to binding to 127.0.0.1:8000](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#bind). I just had to add a flag `-b 0.0.0.0:8000` when running the `gunicorn` command for it to bind to that address.

Comment: I had the same issue, when using nodejs fastify. Had to bind `0.0.0.0`.

`Fastify.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', err => {`

Comment: With FastAPI which runs Uvicorn you bind with `--host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: For NodeJS Express I start app with `express().listen('8090', '0.0.0.0');`

Comment: Can confirm same with swagger

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem but binding to 0.0.0.0 didn't help, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166332/614026) helped me saying that container port should be higher than 1024 because of privileges. I was using default port 80, after exposing 8080 and binding 0.0.0.0 it now started to work

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem using Dockerize GatsbyJS. As [Halil Irmak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8467565/halil-irmak)'s comment, the issue was resolved by binding the application to `0.0.0.0`. On my case

```sh
yarn develop -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
```

Comment: This did the help for me. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem and solved it.

The problem is that, although my HOST config is right, I still receive ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Here's my solution:

**The first time** you start strapi with docker is **really slow**. So if you have done everything right, then **just wait** for the page to start.
I waited 23 mins at the first time...

If you are wondering whether it's slow or something you did is wrong, you can try this:

1. find strapi container id: run `docker ps`
2. enter the container: run `docker exec -it <container id> bash`

   (if you can enter the container, maybe you have done everything right.)
3. check if the port is open: run `echo > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1337`

   When it says 'bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1337: Connection refused', it means your strapi service is not ready yet.

   if the command returns nothing, then strapi service is ready. Check http://127.0.0.1:1337/admin , you will find what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In my case using `node:alpine` on `dockerfile` was the problem for me, just changing the image to the Node.js

It turns out the alpine version is not official. The drawback though is image-size.

I was able to make my API talk normally to my DB passing the DB's container name on the Postgres host variable, and setting up a network in the docker-compose file.

By the way, my setup was Nestjs, TypeORM, Postgres and Docker.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue and changing node:18-alpine to node:18 worked!