# Not able to run CURL from AWS machine against container with python flask code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, curl, postman

I'm created `python` app with `flask`, and successfully tested locally all the `GET` and `POST` calls from `postman`.

Now I'm trying to do the same on `AWS` machine from `Dockerfile`. The `container` is up and running, but I'm not able to test the `GET` and `POST` method.

I tried from postman using the AWS public ip with port 5000 (The `container port`. I opened it from AWS roles for my IP) but I'm getting:
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

Then I tried directly from the machine using `CURL` but I'm getting:
`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: There might be a firewall blocking it.

Comment: How can I check if that's the issue? also, it shouldn't affect when running `curl` command directly form the env, no?

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from and to? The question is a little confusing.

Comment: as I said, I tried first to connect form my local machine using `postman` to my `AWS` machine using public ip and port 5000: `http://{my aws public ip}:5000/v1/api/checkCurrentWeather` but got exception of `ECONNREFUSED`, and after that I tried directly from my env: `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v1/api/checkCurrentWeather` but also got error of `curl (52)`

Comment: I've found the issue. I will post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change in my `app.py` this line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The below helped me get to it:

[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525832/14976099)

[#2](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2522#issuecomment-73934175)