# Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, permissions

When running `npm start` showing this permission issue.

```
 Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1302:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1367:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1454:7)
```

Comment: did you have any service that currently working on port 443 ?

Comment: no, if the port engaged with any service, I think error will be port in use instead of above error message.

Comment: You need root or equivalent privilege to listen on port lesser than 1024. Please run the app with sudo <cmd>

Comment: I tried with `sudo` too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running server with npm on https port 443 was fine with `sudo`. Until I had to upgrade **npm** (from v6 to v8). And googling initially didn't help, because everyone is suggesting `sudo`.

Found duplicate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372618/nodejs-listen-eacces-permission-denied-0-0-0-080).
Referring to [another site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps#give-safe-user-permission-to-use-port-80).

> A lot of people get stuck here, but the solution is easy. There a few options but this is the one I like. Type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin 
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep `readlink -f \`which node\``
```

> Now, when you tell a Node application that you want it to run on port 80, it will not complain.

Comment: This is also a very typical issue when running servers inside a WSL Linux distro. Thank you

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

write with adding sudo.

sudo yarn run dev --port 443