# Cannot connect localhost using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I can see my services using `docker-compose ps`, but I cannot reach them using browser through *localhost:4000* or *localhost:4001*. Always get "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

```
MacBook-Pro-User:my-new-project user$ docker-compose ps
      Name             Command             State              Ports       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
video-storage      docker-            Up                 0.0.0.0:4000->80 
                   entrypoint.sh                         /tcp             
                   /bin/ ...                                              
video-streaming    docker-            Up                 0.0.0.0:4001->80 
                   entrypoint.sh                         /tcp             
                   /bin/ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Inside containers I have Node.js services which listening to PORT 80. It leads to exception `nodejs: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80`.

2 possible solutions:

1. Use port above 1023.
2. Or listen ports as privileged user.

More on this topic:
[nodejs: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372618/nodejs-listen-eacces-permission-denied-0-0-0-080)

[Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)