# ng server - listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200

Tags: angular

I have no problem in do ng serve using 127.0.0.1:4200.

But today, when I do ng serve An unhandled exception occurred: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200

Is there a way to solve this problem permanently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like your port is taken already.

You should kill the use in port 4200.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, and I found out that ntoskrnl.exe is using that port. Is there a way change the port to another one?

Comment: you can use ng serve --port 4211 or change ntoskrnl.exe port

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solve it by disable the World Wide Web Publishing Service. I not sure why this service was started.

Comment: Got a blank browser tab after reboot pointing to 4200. Once you kill it, the issue is gone

Comment: I was using Windows 10 and just restarted my PC twice (without doing anything) and the error is gone.  I followed this: https://superuser.com/questions/1437780/how-to-fix-listen-eacces-permission-denied-on-any-port

Comment: Stopping the World Wide Web Publishing Service was the solution for me! Thanks @JaredTiLianEng for sharing the service name. I was using IIS locally, so that's why it was started.

Answer (score 172):

I have solved this issue by simply going to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` and then I **disabled all** the `Hyper-V Connections/Adapters` and I kept the ones I use like the Wifi and Physical Ethernet Adapter.

No restart needed.
Once done, try to run your Angular app on 4200 and it should work.

***UPDATE***

***Alternative Solutions:***

Sometimes just restarting `Windows NAT` driver can fix the issue:

- open CMD/PowerShell and type `net stop winnat` and then `net start winnat`.

If that did not help then, try to stop the `Windows NAT` Driver and update the ***excludedportrange*** as follows :

- type `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=4200 numberofports=1` if you want to exclude port `4200` only if you want more just update `numberofports`
- then start the `Windows NAT` Driver again and run your App.

Comment: open CMD/PowerShell and type net stop winnat and then net start winnat. this worked for me after wasting so much time for this problem thanks @p90n33r

Comment: @Thili my pleasure, I hope this will be the ultimate solution to this problem

Comment: net stop winnat and restart worked for me

Comment: Faced the same problem. Restarting Windows NAT worked for me in Windows and Angular 12.

Comment: in an administrative cmd, on Windows 10, after successfully stopping the winnat service, I get this on execution the netsh command: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: Just as a fun sidenote: I had this issue, ran `netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` to determine if the port was excluded, which it wasn't, immediately tried serving the Angular app again and it worked. So far this has been reproducible dozens of times for me. If I can't bind to the port because it's seemingly reserved, I list reserved ports to find that it actually isn't, and then binding magically works. Smells fishy/Schrödingery.

Comment: For me the mobile hotspot was active, disabling it fixed the issue

Answer (score 15):

1. check might port already allocated for another application.

> `netstat -ano | findstr "4200"`

2. If you are using Docker might docker allocated this port (stop docker)
3. Final solution restarting PC

Answer (score 12):

It works for me. I did it using adminstration mode in Windows 11

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

Comment: Open PowerShell as Admin -->
stop winnat with command: net stop winnat --> 
start winnat again with command: net start winnat

Answer (score 5):

For me happens after Windows 10 Update to build 2009.

There is a network adapter which is blocking your port.

For @p90n33r was Hyper-V.

For me was Wifi adapter before I use ethernet port.

Try disable any adapters to test it.

No restart needed.

Comment: disableing the Hyper-V adapter worked for me, I did need a restart though

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me while trying to run 2 Angular apps at the same time. So they both targetted 4200 port. I can recommend two solutions.

1. Restart the PC. Very simple.
2. Use a different port for `ng serve -o`

You can modify the package.json file's **start section** as `ng serve -o --port 4401` to make it permanent. (Any port number will do the trick) and on the terminal just execute the command to run the app as `npm start`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, also after rebooting several times. No application using the port. Finally a brainwave to turn off "Azure VPN", which we use locally to connect to our Cloud Network.

So if someone else bumbs into this error: Turn off "Azure VPN" and see if that is the issue. I don't know how to fix it keeping it on.

Answer (score 0):

For me is the Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual which enables by "Screen mirroring and projecting to your PC" Settings.

Just set "Always available" to "Always close" fix it.

Answer (score 0):

***None*** of the previous solutions works for me.

I knew the code of my project was corrupted, but I didn't know how.

Even recloning did **NOT** solve the problem.

I ran "npm i", and it could **NOT** even go installing. So I ran

```
       npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

and it started to install.

And then I ran "npm run start", and it's working.