# Deno : Writing to CSV files on a Docker Container ( Permission denied (os error 13) )

Tags: node.js, docker, deno

I am learning the kinks of Deno and I am having a permissions issue with the writing to a CSV file using the Deno ***writeCSV()*** utility. I have scaffolded the project to run on top Docker

**Dockerfile**

`CMD ["run", "--allow-read",  "--allow-run", "--allow-write", "--allow-net", "main.ts"]`

Main.ts

```
import { serve, readCSV, writeCSV } from "./deps.ts";

const URL = "https://www.getcats.com/api"
const DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
const DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: URL,
  body: {},
  headers: {
    "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};

// CSV File Properties
const f = await Deno.open("./inbound/example.csv");
const outputFile = await Deno.open("./outbound/outbound.csv", { write: true, create: true, read: true, truncate: true });

for await (const row of readCSV(f)) {
  for await (const cell of row) {
    queueMicrotask(async () => {

      const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          "x-api-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          memberId: cell,
          productId: DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ID,
          description: DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION
        }),
      });

      response.json()
        .then(async (res)=> {
          const data = res.data;
          const memberId = data.memberId;
          const hashId = data.id;
          const rows = [memberId, hashId]
          console.log(`CAT ID: ${memberId} - HASH ID: ${hashId}`);                

          await writeCSV(outputFile, rows);
          outputFile.close();

        })

    })

  }
}
f.close();
```

I assume that sending over `---allow-write` when running the container would fix this perm issue. Anyone else having issues writing to directories in Deno over Docker?

Comment: what's happens if you use -A switch instead all those?

Comment: What version of Deno are you using?

Comment: - Running: deno 1.0.0,  v8 8.4.300 , typescript 3.9.2
- I did try to run it with the -A command but no luck

Comment: @victorpalma show your `deps.ts` files, I need to see the dependencies.

Comment: It simply exports from the Deno libraries : 

export { serve } from "deno.land/std@0.50.0/http/server.ts"; 
export { readCSV, writeCSV } from "deno.land/x/csv/mod.ts";

Answer (score 0):

Can you check solution suggestion for very similar issue from blog [here.](https://www.codestack.be/blog/run-deno-containerized-web-application-on-microsoft-azure-container-registry/)

Here is simple problem description:

> One thing I ran into was that initially, the Dockerfile specified a
>   user with limited permissions. This throws a very cryptic exception:

```
error: Uncaught PermissionDenied: Permission denied (os error 13)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendSync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:72:10)
    at Object.listen ($deno$/ops/net.ts:51:10)
    at listen ($deno$/net.ts:152:22)
    at serve (https://deno.land/std@0.50.0/http/server.ts:261:20)
    at file:///app/main.ts:4:11
```

And here is a solution:

> As it turns out, this was because we want to serve the application on
>   `port 80`. `Non-privileged user` (not root) `can't open a listening socket`
>   `on ports below 1024`. Make sure
>   that user running the process (which can be specified by using `USER in`
>   `your Dockerfile`) `has enough permission`. In our case, just `omitting` the
>   `USER` works just fine.

Here is one more [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports) sample.

Comment: Yeah, thats not the issue. Deno is telling me that the following line is failing :

const outputFile = await Deno.open("./outbound/outbound.csv", { write: true, create: true, read: true, truncate: true });