# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 - Digitalocean

Tags: node.js, npm, digital-ocean

I recently followed a [video chat tutorial](https://github.com/amirsanni/Video-Call-App-NodeJS) and wanted to host it on Digitalocean to test some webRTC things. I got it working and even got it hosted on Heroku. However, when I go to host it on an unused droplet (running off of the initial $100 free Digitalocean credit) and SSH into my droplet & run `npm start` (yes, although its not in the tutorials github code, `npm start` **is** in the `package.json`), I get an error.

```
USER***@nodejs-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/DIRNAME$ sudo npm start

> livestream-server@0.0.1 start /home/USER***/DIRNAME
> node app.js

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/USER***/ZMP_Solutions/app.js:17:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! livestream-server@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the livestream-server@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I already read [read this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports) and tried a lot of things, e.g. using `sudo` when running `npm start`, or setting the port to higher than 3000, but none of it helped. Is there a fix to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This means you have a application already using port 3000. Maybe an instance of the same server.

You can close the other process as follows:

```
sudo netstat -lntp | grep 3000
```

to find the process which uses port 3000. Get the PID (Process ID) of that process. The PID is a number written like `PID/ProcessName` like `234/node` in the output, where 234 is the PID. Use it in the following command:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

fill in the PID you found.

Now you can run your server normally and you won't have that error anymore.

Comment: What is the PID? I ran netstat and got: 

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      939/node /var/www/h`
Is the entire thing the PID?

Comment: @divinelemon 939 is the PID

Comment: still throws error. I ran: `sudo kill -9 939` and nothing happened (asked for my password), and then when i ran `npm start` it threw the same error.

Comment: Have you checked again running the `netstat` command if there was still a process running? Normally it should be empty after you ran your kill command

Comment: I did, nothing was there

Answer (score 0):

*Dont set port or higher. Because heroku or the digital ocean will dynamically assign port( whatever will be available)*

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue actually had to do with the Firewall on Digitalocean. All I did was run `sudo ufw disable`, and it worked!!