# WebRTC: Audio Not Showing on Digitalocean Server

Tags: node.js, webrtc, digital-ocean

I recently "finished" my major WebRTC project-- a peer-to-peer video chat for musicians where you can play music at the same time. I just fixed [this annoying error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681215/error-listen-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-3000-digitalocean/63716604#63716604) (took me 2 days to solve, too) but now when I go to my server IP address it shows the start chat, everything, except it doesn't ask to allow video/audio, which results in a blank video slot and not being able to see anyone. Is this an issue with Digitalocean?

Also, you can look at the [Digitalocean](http://143.110.132.205/) one to see going wrong and the [Heroku](https://video-conferencingapp.herokuapp.com/) one to see what it should be doing.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your call to getUserMedia is being blocked by the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: User media not available
at Object.getUserFullMedia (helpers.js:81)
at getAndSetUserStream (rtc.js:103)
at rtc.js:34
```

This happens because it requires the use of https when not on a localhost domain. Your heroku app works because it is using https, Digital Ocean doesn't because it's http.

On http://localhost, your browser allows it for ease of development.

In order for it to work on your digital ocean droplet, you'll want to set up a domain name that points to the droplet and set up an SSL certificate for that server.

Have you thought about just using heroku for this seeing as you've got it set up? They provide all of that for you out of the box with custom domains and SSL certificates.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I actually have thought about hosting it in Heroku, but between the possible chance of Dyno hours and the app idling when not in use, I would much rather prefer to pay for a VPS that doesn't have any of those things. Thanks again!