# How to avoid logging errors from restarting NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, npm

I use NodeJS as a web server on an AWS virtual machine listening on 8443 and leave it running with:

```sh
kill $(lsof -i :8443 | grep .node.bin | cut -d " " -f 2); cd $HOME/server; NODE_ENV=production npm start  >> stdout.txt 2>> stderr.txt &
```

I monitor the error log. Every time I push changes and restart the server, the error log gets several lines, such as:

```
/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin[31215]: ../src/node.cc:663:void node::ResetStdio(): Assertion `(0) == (err)' failed.
 1: 0x9ef190 node::Abort() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 2: 0x9ef217  [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 3: 0x9bd657 node::ResetStdio() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 4: 0x9bd6c0 node::SignalExit(int) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 5: 0x7f7e4922a390  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0]
 6: 0x7f7e48f56ad3 epoll_wait [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 7: 0x13200b0  [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 8: 0x130e26b uv_run [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 9: 0xa31ec3 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
10: 0x9c1cc8 node::Start(int, char**) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
11: 0x7f7e48e6f840 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
12: 0x95c085  [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! EmotionAthletes@0.0.1 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the EmotionAthletes@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bitnami/.npm/_logs/2020-10-25T12_30_23_826Z-debug.log
npm[31199]: ../src/node.cc:663:void node::ResetStdio(): Assertion `(0) == (err)' failed.
 1: 0x9ef190 node::Abort() [npm]
 2: 0x9ef217  [npm]
 3: 0x9bd657 node::ResetStdio() [npm]
 4: 0x7f7db55c4008  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 5: 0x7f7db55c4055  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 6: 0x994907  [npm]
 7: 0xbc9a29  [npm]
 8: 0xbcb817 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm]
 9: 0x13a72b9  [npm]
```

How can I leave it running in the background and avoid logging restart errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [Difference in NodeJS termination errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355026/difference-in-nodejs-termination-errors/65356480#65356480) :

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
let server = httpServer.listen(8080);

process.on("SIGINT", () => {

  // Close main server and HTTP redirection server.
  server.close();
  mongoose.connection.close();
  console.log("SIGINT received, server stopped");
});
```

Then I can stop the server without errors with Control-C (^C) or restart it and leave it running in the background with:

```sh
kill -s SIGINT $(lsof -i :8080 | grep .node.bin | cut -d " " -f 2); cd $HOME/server; cp config.prod.js config.js; NODE_ENV=production npm start  >> stdout.md 2>> stderr.md &
```

In production, the server listens on 8443 for SSL and I have a small server that redirects everything on 8080 to 8443, so I need to stop both servers or else I cannot restart because one port is in use:

```js
let server, httpServer;

const https = require('https');
// SSL configuration
const credentials = {key: sslPrivateKey, cert: sslCertificate};
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
  
server = httpsServer.listen(8443);

// Also create a small server to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

const http = express();

// Set up a route to redirect http to https.
http.get('*', function(req, res) {  
  res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
});

// Have it listen on 8080.
httpServer = http.listen(8080);

process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  // Close main server and HTTP redirection server.
  server.close();
  httpServer.close();
  mongoose.connection.close();
  console.log("SIGINT received, server stopped");
});
```

I use ports 8080 and 8443 for security because ports under 1000 (80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS) are reserved ports. See [Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports). So instead of giving the node server root privileges, I run these shell commands to redirect traffic to on those ports to other ports:

```sh
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```