# Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 8085;

Tags: node.js, port, backend, permission-denied, web-development-server

I tried running the backend server but when I run the command `node backend/server.js` in my cmd, I'm getting this error:

```
D:\theshoppingcart>node backend/server.js
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 8085;
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1284:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1349:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1448:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\theshoppingcart\backend\server.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1328:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '8085;',
  port: -1
}
```

this is my backend/server.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

connectDB();

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8085;

app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: Try this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports).

Comment: @Sega, I guess most of the answers were specific to the code she wrote and port she used and the generic answers didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, you should remove the semicolon ; from the .env file. That has worked for me.

Comment: I'm laughing so hard :D. I have spent almost 1 hour to find out what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `.env` file and check ";".

```
PORT = 5050;
```

You need to remove the ";" from the `.env` file. make it:

```
PORT = 5050
```

Answer (score 0):

YES check ";". or check "," in .env

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows:
you can follow these steps:

1. Launch PowerShell with Administrator privileges.
2. Execute the command to halt winnat:

> ```
>  net stop winnat
> ```

3. Restart winnat by running:

```
net start winnat
```