# NODEJS Error when try to start a prod enviroment

Tags: node.js, production

hope somebody can help me, Im pretty new dealing with prod enviroment, Im trying to deploy my nodejs backend on aws ec2 linux instance. Using pm2 to run the enviroment but after y use **pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production** command and I log the output I've got this logs:

```
at process.emit (events.js:327:22)
at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Error: bind EACCES null:80
at listenOnMasterHandle (net.js:1380:18)
at rr (internal/cluster/child.js:132:12)
at Worker.<anonymous> (internal/cluster/child.js:99:7)
at process.onInternalMessage (internal/cluster/utils.js:47:8)
at process.emit (events.js:327:22)
at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
```

Comment: Is this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports - helpful?

Comment: Thanks @raina77ow I'll going to check it but maybe that works!