# Node.js port permission denied in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, express, port

When I try to start a server in `Express.js` I getting this error:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node main listen.js`
events.js:352
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8090
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1303:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1368:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1454:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\selcuk\Desktop\work\project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\selcuk\Desktop\work\project\listen.js:4:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1347:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 8090
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I try to change the port but it didn't work.
I am using "express": "^4.17.1" and "nodemon": "^2.0.12" as a version.

Comment: Can you add the `package.json`? Also, what is the startup command you are using? You should also add `app`/`server.js` startup screen?

Comment: Did you allow access to the port in the Windows Firewall settings?

Comment: im using startup script as a ``nodemon main``

Comment: Yes i allowed the ``Windows Firewall`` before but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases where nothing is running on the port but some applications or even your code cannot run.  The fix to this:

1. Open PowerShell as an administrator.
2. Stop winnat with: `net stop winnat`
3. Start winnat again with: `net start winnat`

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading the port from an environment variable, convert it to a number first:

```
const httpsPort = Number(process.env.HTTPSPORT) || 3443;
```