# How to connect my mongodb to my nodejs app, resolving .env file error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, .env

//in my .env file

```
MOVIEREVIEWS_DB_URI=mongodb+srv://driiisdev:password123@cluster1.ektx7.mongodb.net/sample_mflix?retryWrites=true&w=majority

PORT=8000 //starting port of server
```

//in my index.js file

```
import app from "./server.js"
import mongodb from "mongodb"
import dotenv from "dotenv"

dotenv.config(); 

const uri = process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_DB_URI;

const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(uri);

const port = process.env.PORT||5000;


(async ()=>{

try{
    //Connect to the MongoDB cluster
    await client.connect();
    app.listen(port, ()=>{
        console.log("server is running on port:" +port);
    })
}catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1)
    }
})().catch(console.error);
```

//in my server.js file

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import movies from './api/movies.route.js'

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use("/api/v1/movies", movies)

app.use('*', (req,res)=>{
    res.status(404).json({error:"not found"})
})

export default app
```

// on running *nodemon server* , the error i get:

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 8000 //starting port of server
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1317:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1382:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1480:5)
at Function.listen (C:\xampp\htdocs\driiisdev\movie-reviews\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
at main (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/driiisdev/movie-reviews/backend/index.js:19:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1361:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '8000 //starting port of server',
port: -1
}

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)?