# Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at: get this error while running server in any PORT

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

This is the code that I am trying to execute, it's a simple code of the project that i recently started working but due to some reason I am getting this error -**Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at: get this error while running server in any PORT.** while running the server. This is the first time I ever have faced this type of problem while working on backend. Kindly, look through it, give the required suggestions or corrections for this code.

```js
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import multer from 'multer';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

// CONFIGURATION
const \__filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const \__dirname = path.dirname(\__filename);
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());

app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(\__dirname, 'public/assets')));

// FILE STORAGE
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function(req, file, cb) {
cb(null, "public/assets");
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, file.originalname);
}
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// MONGOOSE SETUP

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() =\> {`your text`
app.listen(PORT, () =\> console.log(`Server is running in port ${PORT}`));
}).catch((error) =\> console.log(` ${error} did not connect`));
```

Here is the Package.json file for the code -

````
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^16.0.3",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
"helmet": "^6.0.1",
"jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
"mongoose": "^7.0.2",
"morgan": "^1.10.0",
"multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
"multer-gridfs-storage": "^5.0.2"
},
"name": "backend",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon",
"nodemon": "index.js"
},
"keywords": \[\],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"description": ""
}```

The error, I am getting while running the server  - 

```mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, {
^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 8000;
at Server.setupListenHandle \[as \_listen2\] (node:net:1723:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1887:5)
at Function.listen (C:\\STORAGE\\PROJECTS\\Social App\\backend\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\application.js:635:24)
at file:///C:/STORAGE/PROJECTS/Social%20App/backend/index.js:49:9
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1767:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '8000;',
port: -1
}

Node.js v18.15.0
````

To run server in any port provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js EACCES error when listening on most ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports)