# what is the meaning of this error "listen EACCES: permission denied 8000"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is my main file index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.port || 4000;

app.use(express.json());

const createBlog = require("./routes/blogRoutes");

app.use("/santi/api/v1",createBlog);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("App run in 3000 port");
})

const dbConnect = require("./config/database");
dbConnect();

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send(`<h1>this is homepage</h1>`);
})
```

this is my routes

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const {createBlog} = require("../controlers/createBlog");

router.post("/createBlog",createBlog);

module.exports = router;
```

this is my controller file

```
const createPost = require("../models/post");

exports.createBlog= async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const {title,description} = req.body;
        const response = await createPost.create({title,description});

        res.status(200).json({
            status:true,
            message:"Insert seccessfully",
            data:response
        })
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            status:false,
            message:error.message,
            data:"Server issue"
        })
    }
}
```

this is my model file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const blogPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            maxlength:50
        },
        description:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            maxlength:50
        }
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("blogPost",blogPostSchema);
```

Now error is coming after `run npm run dev`. What is the meaning of this error `listen EACCES: permission denied 8000`

```
> blog_backend@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 8000;
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1723:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1887:5)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\SANTI\OneDrive\Desktop\blog_backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SANTI\OneDrive\Desktop\blog_backend\index.js:13:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1767:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '8000;',
  port: -1
}

Node.js v18.14.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Could you help me with the solution?

Comment: How do you start your node server? This message tell you that you can't listen to port 8000. As default port is 4000 in your code, do you change port when starting server?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164915/node-js-eacces-error-when-listening-on-most-ports

Comment: Any chance you already have something running on that port (such as, for example, another instance of the same application)?

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that the address is specified as '8000;' with an extra semicolon at the end. Remove the semicolon from the .env file so that the address is specified correctly as '8000' without any additional characters.

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that your Node.js application is trying to listen on port 8000, but it doesn't have the necessary permissions to do so.

Sometimes port 8000 is used by another service. try a different PORT number